# Signalling a facebook async request has finished

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, block

I have some code which queries facebook for information

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
               NSError *error,) {
                 if (!error) {
                    //populate the **mUser** with data
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"Facebook error encountered: %@", error);
                 }
             }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Facebook session is closed");
        }
```

My question is, what is the best way to tell the caller of the function that facebook is finished? I can't simply return from inside the block (incompatible block pointer types).

The calling code looks like this:

```
    myfacey *fb = [[myfacey alloc] init];
    [fb getUserFromFacebook: mUser];
     //Need to access a populated mUser object here
     //calls to mUser result in nil values because facebook hasn't finished
```

If facebook accessed things synchronously I would have no problem, because mUser would have valid data in it.

Since I have to make asynch calls, what is the best way to signal the calling class that facebook is done populating the variable?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to continue with your program once the asynchronous method has been finished, is putting this code into the completion handler.

Don't try to "return", just "continue" the program in the completion handler.

You should just care about the "execution context" (say thread or dispatch queue) on which the completion handler will be invoked from the async method: if this is not explicitly documented, the completion handler may be called on any thread. So, you might want to dispatch explicitly to the main thread - if necessary:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error,) {
             if (!error) {
                // Continue here with your program.
                ...
                // If you need ensure your code executes on the main thread:
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     // continue with your program on the main thread, for example:
                     // populate the **mUser** with data
                     [self.tableView reloadData];
                     ...
                })
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Facebook error encountered: %@", error);
             }
         }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Facebook session is closed");
    }
```

Comment: I ended up passing a reference to the calling class and calling that function once the  block had finished. Its working quite well. 

Problem with your solution is, you assume my code is in the UI layer, but its in the backend and I need to pass data back up to the UI layer (i.e. the UIViewController classes)

Comment: @FaddishWorm I'm not assuming this ;) it was an example _how_ you can ensure that UIKit methods will be executed on the main thread. The solution you found to solve your issue is (very likely) the right approach (can't tell for sure unless looking at your code): just "continue" your program in the completion handler. This might look strange at the first glance, but this is actually the correct idiom when doing asynchronous stuff. ;)